# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) in find/remove of linked list In C

Tags: c, linked-list

So I am doing a very basic C exercise with a basic linked list. I keep receiving a segmentation error and I'm not too sure what it might be about.

Basically my program adds successfully and then I cant quite tell if the remove or find methods are what are giving me the error.

The structure of the Node is

```
struct Node {
        char * word ;
        struct Node * next ;
} ;
```

I'll attach the add, find, and remove because the rest of the code is of my professors handy-work and that all runs, it is simply the issue I created.

**add**

```
void add_ll( struct Node * anchor, char * word ) {
        // given a pointer to the anchor of the list, and a word, add the word
        // to the list, does not matter where (except don't replace the anchor)
        struct Node * newNode = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)) ;
        newNode -> word = word;
        newNode -> next = anchor -> next;
        anchor -> next = newNode;
        if(anchor == NULL){
          anchor -> next = NULL;
          anchor -> word = word;
      }
      return ;
  }
```

**find**

```
struct Node * find_ll(struct Node * anchor, char * word) {
        // given a pointer to the anchor of the list, and a word, search
        // the list for the word. return the pointer to the with the word, if found,
        // or NULL if not found
        if (anchor -> word == NULL)
          {
            struct Node * node = new_ll();
            return node;
          }
        while(anchor != NULL)
          {
            if(anchor -> word == word)
              return anchor;
            else
              anchor = anchor -> next;
          }
        return NULL ;
}
```

**remove**

```
void remove_ll( struct Node * anchor, struct Node * node_to_remove ) {
        // given a list anchor, and a pointer to a node in the list (but not the anchor)
        // do pointer surgery to remove the node, and free it.
        // sanity checks
        assert(node_to_remove) ;
        assert(node_to_remove!=anchor) ;
        while(anchor != NULL)
          {
            struct Node * temp = anchor;
            struct Node * prev = anchor;
            while(temp != NULL && temp != node_to_remove)
              {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp -> next;
              }
            prev -> next = temp -> next;
            free(temp);
          }
        return ;
}
```

A thing I have tried to see if it would fix it includes changing

`while(temp != NULL && temp -> next != node_to_remove)`
to
 `while(temp != NULL && temp != node_to_remove)`

incase it had something to do with accessing information too early, but it did not fix anything.

Also this is not graded class work if that affects you helping me morally!

So my question basically is... What is causing the segmentation error and if that truly is the only issue, how can I go about fixing it? If you notice any other mistakes please point them out too. I would really appreciate it! If I am missing any information I can add that too! All method headers are my professors and shouldn't be touched!

Comment: "I cant quite tell if the remove or find methods are what are giving me the error". That's what a debugger can tell you almost immediately. Time to fire it up. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It's better if you indent code with four spaces or use the `{}` to do that for you.

Comment: In `add`, follow the flow if `anchor` is NULL

Comment: In find, you are checking anchor->word==NULL but what happens when anchor is NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't know when the error occurs, I don't either.

But I see an issue in `add`:

```
if(anchor == NULL) {
    anchor -> next = NULL;
    anchor -> word = word;
}
```

If `anchor` is NULL, then setting it's properties is going to crash your program. NULL is not a valid pointer and should never be used.

And in `find`:

```
while(anchor != NULL)
{
    if(anchor -> word == word)
        return anchor;
    else
        anchor = anchor -> next;
}
```

Do you understand what `anchor->word == word` does? If both point to the same string, it will return false because it is comparing the pointers. That is, it's comparing the address of each string. It will only return true if both pointers point to the same memory. Look at `strcmp()` to compare the string.

And in `remove`:

```
while(anchor != NULL)
{
    struct Node * temp = anchor;
    struct Node * prev = anchor;

    while(temp != NULL && temp != node_to_remove)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    prev -> next = temp -> next;
    free(temp);
}
```

So, this doesn't seem quite right either. For one thing, if `temp` is ever NULL, then `temp = temp->next` will be accessing a NULL pointer. Again, NULL is an invalid pointer and should never be used. Overall, I would complete rewrite this. I can't see any reason for nested loops. One loop should be enough. And the logic needs to be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

The function `add_ll()` will break if `anchor` is NULL, but constructs a valid list otherwise.  I noticed that it does not make a copy of the string into the `Node` structure.  Is this what's desired?  It seems weird to add the new element after the head of the list.  Typically the simplest way is to just create a new head-node.

```
struct Node *add_ll( struct Node *anchor, char *word ) 
{
    // given a pointer to the anchor of the list, and a word, add the word
    // to the list, does not matter where (except don't replace the anchor)
    // returns the new list

    struct Node * new_node = (struct Node *)malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->word = word;
        new_node->next = anchor;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Handle Out of memory error
    }

    return new_node;
}
```

When a new node is created, perhaps with a NULL `anchor`, it creates a new list.  The new item is always added at the head of the list:

```
struct Node *my_list = NULL;
...
my_list = add_ll( my_list, "some string" );
```

I don't really understand the reasoning behind some parts of `find_ll()`.  Why would it create a new empty(?) node.  A better implementation might be:

```
struct Node *find_ll( struct Node *anchor, char *word ) 
{
    // given a pointer to the anchor of the list, and a word, search
    // the list for the word. return the pointer to the Node with the word, if found,
    // or NULL if not found

    struct Node *result = NULL;

    while( anchor != NULL )
    { 
        if ( anchor->word == word )         // Should this be a strcmp()?
        {
            result = anchor;                // found it
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            anchor = anchor->next;          // skip to the next item
        }
    }

    return result;                          // PRO-TIP: return from a single place
}
```

And the `remove_ll()` - How can this remove the "head" element from the list?  It needs to return a modified list somehow.

```
struct Node *remove_ll( struct Node *anchor, struct Node *node_to_remove ) 
{
    struct Node *result = anchor;

    // given a list anchor, and a pointer to a node in the list (but not the anchor)
    // do pointer surgery to remove the node, and free it.
    // return a pointer to the changed list

    // sanity checks
    assert( anchor );
    assert( node_to_remove );

    // Case where head-node is to be removed
    if ( node_to_remove == anchor )
    {
        // make a new head
        result = anchor->next;                              // snip (of head)
    }
    else
    {
        while( anchor->next != NULL )
        {
            if ( anchor->next == node_to_remove )
            {
                // point to anchor's next-next, removing the node
                anchor->next = node_to_remove->next;   // snip (in body)
            }
            else
            {
                // no match, search ahead
                anchor = anchor->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This way removing the head could be called:

```
my_list = remove_ll( my_list, head_node );
```

And the `my_list` might have the same head as before, or the 2nd-node.